# How Wifi connection is maintained

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

Recently I was reading about how IPs are assigned to a new system (DHCP) and how systems communicates in LAN (ARP). But I am not able to understand how wifi actually works? What I understand is WiFi router uses radio waves (not sure) and it is having transmitter and receiver which transmits only Yes/No Signal, and it is having frequency 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz

So Can anybody answer following questions

1. what signal pattern is actually used?
2. is the connection between system & router continuous -- i.e router continuously sends signal or at regular interval?
3. when a router is switched off, how is a laptop/system notified? Does router sends any special signal?

Comment: You're asking how a "layer-0" technology works. We're *network engineers*, not *RF engineers*. As such, we generally don't care how it's signaled. (just like we don't care how ethernet, DSL, or DOCSIS is electrically signaled.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WiFi, there are two types of devices: Access Point (ap), and Station (sta). In simple terms, "router" would be the AP, and the client systems are STA. Stations know an AP exists and is in range because the AP broadcasts "beacons" -- by default every 100ms (10 beacons per second.) Within the beacon there's an (optional) informational element listing the SSIDs the AP handles.

Only one radio (transmitter) can be active at a time. So there is no "continuous" signal. This is true of any RF system... CB radio, walkie-talkie, etc.

When the beacons stop, clients know the AP is dead -- or rapidly moved out of range. If the AP is rebooted or otherwise gracefully shutdown, it can send "deauth" frames to each station to force them to disassociate (disconnect) from the AP.

Comment: Thanks Ricky for such a nice explanation. I understood 1 & 3 point. But I am still not clear about the second point u made, u said there is no continuous signal BUT in **first point** u said that **By Default AP broadcast 10 beacons/second.**   So AP is maintaining a continuous signal isn't it?? And one more thing Can you please share some links which will be helpful

Comment: With a CB radio/walkie, what happens when you hold the mic button down? That's "continuous transmit". In WiFi (and most RF in general), the transmitter is only active during transmission of a frame. The rest of the time, the transmitter is silent so the receiver can clearly hear other stations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wifi uses the 802.11 protocol.  You can find numerous sources to study about it on the Internet.
2. Wifi communication is half-duplex, meaning the router (actually, an Access Point) and the laptop take turns talking.
3. No special signal.  The protocol defines who can talk and when.

From a high level point of view, wifi works the same way as Ethernet or frame relay or any number of media types.